# Intellij 14 Scala plugin 1.4: Play project not launching

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.3, intellij-14

Today I got an update on Scala from 1.3.x to 1.4 After that, Intellij stopped launching my play projects.

First when I would try to run activator from the command line, it gave me the following error

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile <path to project>\activator-launch-1.2.8.jar
```

So I replaced all the activator files from within the project. Then it started to run from the teriminal/console but when I hit Run/Debug on the my Play configuration in Intellij it simply makes the project and then nothing happens. It doesn't launch in the browser. There are no errors in the event log; just compilation successful message.

I'm using the exact same project from yesterday with no changes apart from installing the new scala plugin.

I tried reverting back to 1.3 on scala, but it keeps saying that version is not compatible with the new Intellij.

I am using a Win 8 machine 64 bit.

**Temporary Solution:**

As a quick fix for now, I installed an older version of the plugin from here - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+plugin+EAP

I installed Scala plugin 1.4 RC (1.3.110.35.EAP) and it worked.
Just make sure you do not select to auto-update your plugins or when you restart it will ask you to update the scala plugin, do not click that.

It's running for now but it would be good to have a fix for this soon.

**IntelliJ Tickets**

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8484

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8512

Comment: Do you find the jar file there?  I know they restructured how the Scala plugin works with the new version, so it may just not be looking in the right place for that jar.

Comment: I added a jar file explicitly, it still gave the same result. So I removed all the activator files and added a new set from a newer version. Then it started to work from command line but it still doesn't launch in Intellij. Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: It sounds like something along the lines of IntelliJ not correctly understanding the Play project - this might happen when an SBT project changes the standard directories, as is the case with Play.  I'd recommend checking the known bugs of IntelliJ, and if you can't find one, maybe make one.  Also, I think there's a Play framework plugin for IntelliJ - have you tried installing it?

Comment: Yes, I was working on this project for the last 3 months. I used IntelliJ 14 for the last 6 weeks and it was the same Play project. Working like normal. Then I did the scala plugin update and it stopped working. I have checked Intellij bugs and I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue after updating the scala plugin. My project doenst launch after it 'make's sucessfully.. Did you guys already find something about that?

Comment: I also got this problem today after upgrading to Scala v1.4 plugin.
My projects "makes" successfully but then cannot launch. I noticed that Scala facet is absent in the project structure and cannot be added.
That's a pity that plugin upgrade brakes the stuff.

Comment: I filed request to JetBrains. Let's see what they will reply.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar can you please post the link of the bug request you just filed? Thanks!

Comment: It's good to know I'm not the only one with this issue. Phew! I thought I did something wrong and broke everything!

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/56149

Comment: @AlexanderArendar any fix yet?

Comment: There is a fix which worked for me. It's in the support ticket or read comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187134/play-project-does-not-run-after-jetbrains-scala-plugin-ugraded-to-v1-4

Comment: @AlexanderArendar Thanks I have been doing that but I prefer intellij because the terminal on windows is not great. As I mentioned in my question, I have downgraded.

Comment: They promised to include the fix in next stable release. So I have just installed that latest nightly build from downloaded zip for now and it works for me.

Comment: Good to hear! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed v1.4.15 and it launches the Play application as expected.
Thank you!