# Play project does not run after JetBrains Scala plugin ugraded to v1.4

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

After upgrading Scala plugin in IntelliJ IDEA 14 to v1.4 my Play project ceased to run.
It can "make" the project successfully but cannot launch web-app.
The project was in working state for months and there were no problems.
I noticed that Scala facet is not available now, even if I create a new Play/Scala project.
My problem is not unique if you look at the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144363/intellij-14-scala-plugin-1-4-play-project-not-launching).

Is it the problem of plugin or something I am missing?

Comment: Guys, I have set up 1.3.139 version of the plugin from the nightly build dated March 20th as advised by the JetBrains support and it fixed the problem.
You may access it here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly+Builds+for+Cassiopeia

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing same problem and can't downgrade the plugin to 1.3.3 or lower (another IDEA bug? ) and opened an issue

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-138008

I'm pretty sure it's an issue on IDEA/Plugin side since you still can run and debug your application in IDEA with activator:

Run it in directory of your Play2 application

- to run in DEV mode `activator run RUN_PORT`
- to run in PROD mode `activator start START_PORT`
- to debug `activator -jvm-debug DEBUG_PORT "run RUN_PORT"`

Substitute PORTs with your ports (usually RUN_PORT is 9000 and DEBUG_PORT is 9999).

For debugging in IDEA:

1. create new configuration "Menu Run -> Edit configuration..."
2. click on "+" sign "Add new configuration" and choose "Remote" in drop-down list.
3. Settings of configuration are default (Transport: Socket, Debugger mode: Attach)
4. Enter host and debug port where your app is running (running locally with DEBUG_PORT 9999 -> enter "localhost" and "9999")
5. After creating this configuration select it and press Debug button.

Comment: thanks, it's usefull info to know that I can run with activator

Comment: You can downgrade now. I have been using the activator as well but I still prefer using the debug on IntelliJ. See here under temporary solution in the question for how to downgrade - http://stackoverflow.com/q/29144363/462285